# Changing button value on button click

Tags: javascript, xpages

Just starting out in Xpages and ran into a silly problem:

I have a button (id- "button2") and it has label "aaa". What I'm trying to do is to change the value of the button on the button click to value "kappa123". I've included my JavaScript in the "Client" tab in Script Editor.

JavaScript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("button2");
if (elem.value=="aaa") elem.value="kappa123";
else elem.value = "aaa";
```

I don't even a error and nothing happens. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
var elem = document.getElementById("#{id:button2}");
if (elem.innerHTML=="aaa") elem.innerHTML="kappa123";
else elem.innerHTML = "aaa";
```

You can't use the element id in client side code direct as the id gets "renamed" by XPages. With `#{id:button2}` you get the rendered id.

Comment: Still nothing. I think I might have problems with client not the script that i wrote... Weird stuff. EDIT: Okay, now I'm confused. The client seems to work just fine, tested the button with alert ("text"); and the code worked.

Comment: this CSJS solution breaks on partial/full refresh. binding `label` attribute of button component is IMO better solution.

Answer (score 1):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bL07bruf/2/)

```
   jQuery('#button2').click(function(){
   var elem = document.getElementById("button2");
    if (elem.value=="aaa") jQuery("#button2").attr('value', 'If');
     else jQuery("#button2").attr('value', 'Else');
     alert(elem.value);
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
        var elem = document.getElementById("button2");
        elem.innerHTML="Working.";
```

it works with `<button> </button>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually works fine for me.

```
<input id="button2" onclick="test()" type="button" value="aaa"/>
<script>
    function test(){ 
      var elem = document.getElementById("button2");
      if (elem.value=="aaa") elem.value="kappa123";
      else elem.value = "aaa";
      }

</script>
```

Here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/Sourabh_/yezh3e9q/

Comment: You can also change using

 jQuery('#button2').click(function(){
       var elem = document.getElementById("button2");
if (elem.value=="aaa") jQuery("#button2").attr('value', 'If'); 
else  jQuery("#button2").attr('value', 'else');  
});